# Closing specific figures does not work as I need - it just cleares them

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, matlab-figure, figure

I have a GUI in Matlab, where I can plot many figures, I have named them specifically, and now I'm currently working on a delete function, after clicking on a button connected to the function, I want the figures get closed (not only cleared, but closed), but it cleares them instead.

Code below:

```
if exist('Vectorcardiogram')
close('Vectorcardiogram')
return
end

if exist('Planes')
close('Planes')
return
end

if exist('P wave')
close('P wave')
return
end

if exist('QRS complex')
close('QRS complex')
return
end

if exist('T wave')
close('T wave')
return
end
```

As you can see, I can plot 5 figures in total, but I don't need to plot all of them always, so that's why I wrote the code that way it is.

Could you please help me, why is it clearing the specified figure windows instead of closing them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get a `handle` to your figure first:

```
%Open figure named 'Vectorcardiogram'
figure('Name', 'Vectorcardiogram');

%Return handle to figure named 'Vectorcardiogram'.
h = findobj('Name', 'Vectorcardiogram');

%Close figure.
close(h);
```

---

More elegant solution is saving handle to figure, when open it, then use handle for closing the figure.

Example:

```
Vectorcardiogram_handle = figure('Name', 'Vectorcardiogram');
%...
%...
close(Vectorcardiogram_handle);
```